# How to improve text processing performance in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, text-processing, lazy-sequences

I'm writing a simple desktop search engine in Clojure as a way to learn more about the language. Until now, the performance during the text processing phase of my program is really bad.

During the text processing I've to:

- Clean up unwanted characters;
- Convert the string to lowercase;
- Split the document to get a list of words;
- Build a map which associates each word to its occurrences in the document.

Here is the code:

```
(ns txt-processing.core
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as cjio])
  (:require [clojure.string :as cjstr])
  (:gen-class))

(defn all-files [path]
  (let [entries (file-seq (cjio/file path))]
    (filter (memfn isFile) entries)))

(def char-val
  (let [value #(Character/getNumericValue %)]
    {:a (value \a) :z (value \z)
     :A (value \A) :Z (value \Z)
     :0 (value \0) :9 (value \9)}))

(defn is-ascii-alpha-num [c]
  (let [n (Character/getNumericValue c)]
    (or (and (>= n (char-val :a)) (<= n (char-val :z)))
        (and (>= n (char-val :A)) (<= n (char-val :Z)))
        (and (>= n (char-val :0)) (<= n (char-val :9))))))

(defn is-valid [c]
    (or (is-ascii-alpha-num c)
        (Character/isSpaceChar c)
        (.equals (str \newline) (str c))))

(defn lower-and-replace [c]
  (if (.equals (str \newline) (str c)) \space (Character/toLowerCase c)))

(defn tokenize [content]
  (let [filtered (filter is-valid content)
        lowered (map lower-and-replace filtered)]
    (cjstr/split (apply str lowered) #"\s+")))

(defn process-content [content]
  (let [words (tokenize content)]
    (loop [ws words i 0 hmap (hash-map)]
      (if (empty? ws)
        hmap
        (recur (rest ws) (+ i 1) (update-in hmap [(first ws)] #(conj % i)))))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (doseq [file (all-files (first args))]
    (let [content (slurp file)
          oc-list (process-content content)]
      (println "File:" (.getPath file)
               "| Words to be indexed:" (count oc-list )))))
```

As I have [another implementation](https://gist.github.com/luisgabriel/5474695) of this problem in Haskell, I compared both as you can see in the following outputs.

Clojure version:

```
$ lein uberjar
Compiling txt-processing.core
Created /home/luisgabriel/projects/txt-processing/clojure/target/txt-processing-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Including txt-processing-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Including clojure-1.5.1.jar
Created /home/luisgabriel/projects/txt-processing/clojure/target/txt-processing-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
$ time java -jar target/txt-processing-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar ../data
File: ../data/The.Rat.Racket.by.David.Henry.Keller.txt | Words to be indexed: 2033
File: ../data/Beyond.Pandora.by.Robert.J.Martin.txt | Words to be indexed: 1028
File: ../data/Bat.Wing.by.Sax.Rohmer.txt | Words to be indexed: 7562
File: ../data/Operation.Outer.Space.by.Murray.Leinster.txt | Words to be indexed: 7754
File: ../data/The.Reign.of.Mary.Tudor.by.James.Anthony.Froude.txt | Words to be indexed: 15418
File: ../data/.directory | Words to be indexed: 3
File: ../data/Home.Life.in.Colonial.Days.by.Alice.Morse.Earle.txt | Words to be indexed: 12191
File: ../data/The.Dark.Door.by.Alan.Edward.Nourse.txt | Words to be indexed: 2378
File: ../data/Storm.Over.Warlock.by.Andre.Norton.txt | Words to be indexed: 7451
File: ../data/A.Brief.History.of.the.United.States.by.John.Bach.McMaster.txt | Words to be indexed: 11049
File: ../data/The.Jesuits.in.North.America.in.the.Seventeenth.Century.by.Francis.Parkman.txt | Words to be indexed: 14721
File: ../data/Queen.Victoria.by.Lytton.Strachey.txt | Words to be indexed: 10494
File: ../data/Crime.and.Punishment.by.Fyodor.Dostoyevsky.txt | Words to be indexed: 10642

real    2m2.164s
user    2m3.868s
sys     0m0.978s
```

Haskell version:

```
$ ghc -rtsopts --make txt-processing.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( txt-processing.hs, txt-processing.o )
Linking txt-processing ...
$ time ./txt-processing ../data/ +RTS -K12m
File: ../data/The.Rat.Racket.by.David.Henry.Keller.txt | Words to be indexed: 2033
File: ../data/Beyond.Pandora.by.Robert.J.Martin.txt | Words to be indexed: 1028
File: ../data/Bat.Wing.by.Sax.Rohmer.txt | Words to be indexed: 7562
File: ../data/Operation.Outer.Space.by.Murray.Leinster.txt | Words to be indexed: 7754
File: ../data/The.Reign.of.Mary.Tudor.by.James.Anthony.Froude.txt | Words to be indexed: 15418
File: ../data/.directory | Words to be indexed: 3
File: ../data/Home.Life.in.Colonial.Days.by.Alice.Morse.Earle.txt | Words to be indexed: 12191
File: ../data/The.Dark.Door.by.Alan.Edward.Nourse.txt | Words to be indexed: 2378
File: ../data/Storm.Over.Warlock.by.Andre.Norton.txt | Words to be indexed: 7451
File: ../data/A.Brief.History.of.the.United.States.by.John.Bach.McMaster.txt | Words to be indexed: 11049
File: ../data/The.Jesuits.in.North.America.in.the.Seventeenth.Century.by.Francis.Parkman.txt | Words to be indexed: 14721
File: ../data/Queen.Victoria.by.Lytton.Strachey.txt | Words to be indexed: 10494
File: ../data/Crime.and.Punishment.by.Fyodor.Dostoyevsky.txt | Words to be indexed: 10642

real    0m9.086s
user    0m8.591s
sys     0m0.463s
```

I think the (*string* -> *lazy sequence*) conversion in the Clojure implementation is killing the performance. How can I improve it?

P.S: All the code and data used in these tests can be downloaded [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5798150/txt-processing.zip).

Comment: what is the JVM startup time for the jar? Does Haskell have similar overhead?

Comment: the JVM startup time in my machine is around one second. I think Haskell has some overhead due the runtime system (RTS), but I should be considerably lower than the JVM.

Comment: s/I should/it should/

Comment: Use `(inc i)` instead of `(+ i 1)`

Comment: @luisgabriel: Could you post the end version and it's results as well ?

Comment: sure. you can find it here: https://gist.github.com/luisgabriel/45d9a4fae7d35cf4b0e8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some things you could do that would probably speed this code up:

1) Instead of mapping your `chars` to `char-val`, just do direct value comparisons between the characters.  This is faster for the same reason it would faster in Java.

2) You repeatedly use `str` to convert single-character values to full-fledged strings.  Again, consider using the character values directly. Again, object creation is slow, same as in Java.

3) You should replace `process-content` with `clojure.core/frequencies`. Perhaps inspect `frequencies` source to see how it is faster.

4) If you must update a `(hash-map)` in a loop, use `transient`. See: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/transient

Also note that `(hash-map)` returns a `PersistentArrayMap`, so you are creating new instances with each call to `update-in` - hence slow and why you should use transients.

5) This is your friend: `(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)` - You have quite a bit of reflection that could benefit from [type hints](http://kotka.de/blog/2012/06/Did_you_know_IX.html)

```
 Reflection warning, scratch.clj:10:13 - call to isFile can't be resolved.
 Reflection warning, scratch.clj:13:16 - call to getNumericValue can't be resolved.
 Reflection warning, scratch.clj:19:11 - call to getNumericValue can't be resolved.
 Reflection warning, scratch.clj:26:9 - call to isSpaceChar can't be resolved.
 Reflection warning, scratch.clj:30:47 - call to toLowerCase can't be resolved.
 Reflection warning, scratch.clj:48:24 - reference to field getPath can't be resolved.
 Reflection warning, scratch.clj:48:24 - reference to field getPath can't be resolved.
```

Comment: perfect! just putting the type hints the total time decreased to 7s! ;)

Comment: I cannot use `clojure.core/frequencies` because I need the word positions to further phases like indexing and querying.

Answer (score 0):

Just for comparison's sake, here's a regexp based Clojure version

```
(defn re-index
     "Returns lazy sequence of vectors of regexp matches and their start index" 
     [^java.util.regex.Pattern re s]
     (let [m (re-matcher re s)]
       ((fn step []
          (when (. m (find))
            (cons (vector (re-groups m)(.start m)) (lazy-seq (step))))))))

(defn group-by-keep
  "Returns a map of the elements of coll keyed by the result of
  f on each element. The value at each key will be a vector of the
  results of r on the corresponding elements."
  [f r coll]  
  (persistent!
    (reduce
      (fn [ret x]
        (let [k (f x)]
          (assoc! ret k (conj (get ret k []) (r x)))))
      (transient {}) coll)))

(defn word-indexed
  [s]
  (group-by-keep
    (comp clojure.string/lower-case first)
    second
    (re-index #"\w+" s)))
```